# Can a TCP Socket SendAsync operation complete without transferring all the bytes in a BufferList?

Tags: c#, sockets, mono

On Mono 3.12, I'm using [`Socket.SendAsync(SocketAsyncEventArgs)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.socket.sendasync(v=vs.110).aspx) with a TCP Stream `Socket` to implement a request-based streaming protocol. I'm using [`SocketAsyncEventArgs.BufferList`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.socketasynceventargs.bufferlist(v=vs.110).aspx) to set multiple buffers of data.

In the documentation for [`Socket`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.socket_methods(v=vs.110).aspx) and [`SocketAsyncEventArgs`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.socketasynceventargs(v=vs.110).aspx), I can't find any mention of whether the [`SocketAsyncEventArgs.Completed`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.socketasynceventargs(v=vs.110).aspx) can be raised without all bytes being sent when `BufferList` is used, leaving the impression that we have to validate against [`SocketAsyncEventArgs.BytesTransferred`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.socketasynceventargs.bytestransferred(v=vs.110).aspx).

On the other hand, [`Socket.BeginSend`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7h44aee9(v=vs.110).aspx) makes that guarantee

> When your application calls `BeginSend`, the system will use a
>   separate thread to execute the specified callback method, and will
>   block on `EndSend` **until the `Socket` sends the number of bytes
>   requested or throws an exception.**

What guarantees does the specification make about the number of bytes transferred when using `SendAsync` with a `SocketAsyncEventArgs.BufferList`?

Assume that the event was completed with [`SocketError.Success`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.socketerror(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: I think the question would be: "Can the `SocketAsyncEventArgs.Completed` handler be invoked without a socket error and `e.BytesTransferred != length`?" From what I can gather under .NET Framework is not possible: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28675811/when-i-call-wsasend-will-all-the-data-be-sent and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14347708/calling-wsasend-in-completion-port

Comment: Can you provide some code for testing?

Comment: @DieterMeemken What do you need to test to answer _What guarantees does the specification make_? As I mention, I'm using `SendAsync` with `SocketAsyncEventArgs` with a set `BufferList`.

Comment: After looking at the .NET implementation, look like it is guaranteed to send all the bytes on Unix and on Windows. It that the answer are you looking for?

Comment: @ShmuelH. Unfortunately, not. Mono uses `sendmsg` on linux, which doesn't make that guarantee. I'd like to know if it's a bug on Mono or if I need to adapt the pattern I use to send all the bytes.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis .NET on Linux uses `sendmsg` too. But it also checks if all the buffers has been sent.

Comment: @ShmuelH. Can you link to the source you're browsing in Core? Mono's doesn't seem to do that, at least from taking tcpdumps (see previous edit revision of this question).

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis See [here](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/684af05e70b345eecd503e23d0d6d4efd67f9130/src/System.Net.Sockets/src/System/Net/Sockets/SocketPal.Unix.cs#L216). This code calculates the next index and offset to be send (on partial action, it would start from next unsent byte). See also `TryCompleteSendTo`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/133759/discussion-between-shmuel-h-and-sotirios-delimanolis).

Comment: I know this question is "old" but I have the same question and there doesn't seem to be a accepted answer yet. From the comments (and other questions) it looks like all bytes will be sent for the "normal"/Windows .NET but I can't find any specific answer if this is also true for .NET Core (Linux) and stuff like Mono (Unity game engine). Can anyone confirm this please? I guess for now the "best" solution is to either implement the logic to handle this case or write a log / throw a error so you at least notice that not all bytes where sent in your specific .NET version/target?

Comment: Also in my opinion Completed for a send should not be called until a error happens or all bytes are sent (like in the current .NET/Windows implementation) if any other implementation does something else it should be reported as a bug in the specific implementation in my opinion, because it's not "completed" if only some bytes were sent (unless it stops because of a error, but that's a different case)

Comment: [A bug report was filed against Mono](https://github.com/mono/mono/issues/10533) whose expected behavior is that all bytes are sent. However, it hasn't received any (definite) comments like this question.

Answer (score 2):

**What guarantees does the specification make about the number of bytes transferred when using SendAsync with a `SocketAsyncEventArgs.BufferList`?**

To start with, the event can be raised on errors in which case you can assume that not all bytes have been transferred. For this you need to test the SocketAsyncEventArgs.SocketError for SocketError.Success. Also, if you refer to 'specification' I assume you mean the (Microsoft) Windows Sockets documentation (since you link to this for the SendAsync and other descriptions).

In order too make out what the documentation says or implies for the number of transferred bytes when the Completed event is called in case of success, we have to make a few steps. The first step is to see if SendAsync uses overlapped I/O. That question is answered in the [Overlapped Input / Output](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms740086(v=vs.85).aspx) documentation. Implementation for this mechanism is mandatory for underlying transport providers and hence it is the only overlapped I/O mechanism that is guaranteed to be available for Windows Sockets. As such, SendAsync is guaranteed to use a socket with the WSA_FLAG_OVERLAPPED attribute.

Note that inspection of the [SendAsync reference implementation](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System/net/System/Net/Sockets/Socket.cs) shows that SendAsync is indeed using WSASend with overlapped I/O, but that’s merely an observation.

The second step is to determine what overlapped I/O tells us about the signalling of the completed event related the amount of transferred bytes. This situation is described in several places, for example at this [Overlapped I/I and Event Objects](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms740087(v=vs.85).aspx) page: ‘indication will be provided when send buffers have been consumed’. A little more detail is given in the remarks section for the [WSASend] function: ‘A completion indication will occur, invoking the completion of a routine or setting of an event object, when the buffer(s) have been consumed by the transport’.

This still leaves some room for the exact interpretation of this phrase. Basically it says that the data was accepted and confirmed by an underlying transport mechanism out of the socket scope. This does not necessarily mean it has arrived at the remote endpoint protocol layer, this would depend on the communication protocol. For a TCP streaming socket I would infer that it indicates that the data has arrived at the  remote endpoint.

The conclusion here is that the documentation guarantees (for a non-error situation) that the SendAsync completed event is raised only at the point when all bytes have been transferred.

Comment: Yes, let's assume for `SocketError.Success` only. I'll edit my question. I'm not convinced. When I link to the documentation, my intention is to link to the .Net standard libraries which should be implemented by all .Net runtimes, not just Windows.  Windows implementation does it one way, but is that the only correct way?

Comment: Is this also true for .NET Core (which can run on Linux) or Mono (for example used by the Unity game engine) which can also run on different plattforms?

Answer (score -2):

What are you trying to check here? Are you concerned about why you are not receiving all bytes when all bytes are sent?

When you send 100 bytes at one shot and try to read 100 bytes at the other end, there is not guarantee that you will receive all bytes at one shot. It could be broken into 100 packets of 1 byte. That's how TCP works. You always need to accumulate bytes and then form and separate your packets. That's called TCP socket plumbing effort. WCF and all those wrappers do it for you.